# Django - How to pass current url parameters if any to a new url after pressing a button

Tags: django, url, parameters

My current page has a filter that the user can fill if wanted.

```
def charts_wallet_view(request):

 result = {}
 filtered_date1 = request.GET.get('fecha_inicio', '')
 filtered_date2 = request.GET.get('fecha_fin', '')
 context = {
    'mes_inicio' : mes_inicio,
    'mes_fin' : mes_fin,
    }
 return render(request, 'wallet.html', context)
```

In wallet.html there is a button that redirects the user to a new url that downloads a file:

```
<a class="gpg-button egp secondary no_decoration" href="{% url "export_wallet" %}">
```

My question is: How I can pass the parameters (fecha_inicio and fecha_fin) to the new url/view? First i thought on doing something like that:

```
<a class="gpg-button egp secondary no_decoration" href="{% url "export_wallet" mes_inicio mes_fin %}">
```

But it does not work. Then I though that i also need to add the two parameters in the url.py too:

```
path('export_wallet/<str:mes_inicio>/<str:fecha_fin >', views.export_wallet_view, name='export_wallet')
```

And in the export_wallet view:

```
def charts_wallet_view(request, mes_inicio,mes_fin):
  #view logic
```

But this does not work when no value is passed in the parameters.

Comment: Hello, you can post your code here and it will help people help you. Right now it is hard to figure out what exactly is your problem. It might be a frontend problem, it might be a django problem or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT since the question changed:
It makes more sense to do a POST here probably instead of a GET.

```
path('export_wallet/', views.export_wallet_view, name='export_wallet'),
```

```css
.inline {
  display: inline;
}

.link-button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: serif;
}
.link-button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.link-button:active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="{% url 'export_wallet' %}" class="inline">
  <input type="hidden" name="fecha_inicio" value="{{ fecha_inicio }}">
<input type="hidden" name="fecha_fin" value="{{ fecha_fin }}">
  <button type="submit" name="submit_param" value="submit_value" class="link-button">
    This is a link that sends a POST request
  </button>
</form>
```

then in your export_wallet_view:

```
fecha_fin = request.POST.get("fecha_fin")
```

Comment: Hi, i am passing the parameters in the context and in the template i can pass them to the url like you suggest. But the problem i have is how to define the 'export wallet' url so it accepts the parameters in the context when they have value.

Comment: i also edited my post to make things clearer. thanks

Comment: You want two variables but your URL string is only looking for one variable. Try:
'export_wallet/<str:fecha_inicio >/<str:fecha_fin >'

Comment: really a better way to do this is probably to use a POST instead of a GET

Comment: hi, yes i missed here the 2nd variable. the thing is that this work but only when the parameters has value. If they do not have value the view is expecting the 2 values.

Comment: see my edit - this way if there is no data in the form you can deal with that in the view, it should fix all your problems

Comment: thanks a lot, the form was the answer to my problem!

Comment: you're welcome - please mark the question as answered